# Prevent null values to being written in SQLite with PDO Php in Online Counter

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, null

I have a php script that counts how many users are online at any given time using php, sqlite and PDO. I using apache 2.4.53 and php 8.0.19 both at 64bit. The problem is that null values ​​are often written inside the database which cause the counter to increment unnecessarily and which are not canceled in any way, I have tried everything to eliminate the null values ​​that are written but I have not succeeded:

```
  $deleteNull = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM online WHERE last_activity IS NULL AND id IS NULL');
  $deleteNull->execute();
```

But is not working, I only found a trick that only counts the values ​​that are not null but obviously it is a hack because in the database these null values ​​are there and they remain there without being able to delete them:

```
$count = $db->query('SELECT COUNT() AS visitors FROM online WHERE last_activity IS NOT NULL AND id IS NOT NULL')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

In the screenshot you can see 2 columns and 3 rows, 2 rows are legit, the 3rd is fake since is null. The result is that counter counts 3 visitors instead of 2. This happens on Linux machines (CentOS).

Is there any way to modify the script to prevent these null values ​​from being written in database?

```
<?php
  if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
  }
  $_SESSION['id'] = (isset($_SESSION['id'])) ? $_SESSION['id'] : uniqid();
  $secondsToConsiderOffline = 60;
  $hitonlinedb = "online.sqlite";
  try {
    if (!file_exists($hitonlinedb)) {
      $db = new PDO("sqlite:" . $hitonlinedb);
      $db->exec('CREATE TABLE online(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, last_activity INTEGER)');
    } else {
      $db = new PDO("sqlite:" . $hitonlinedb);
    }
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
  }
  $currentTime = time();
  $gracePeriod = $currentTime - $secondsToConsiderOffline;
  $id = $_SESSION['id'];
  $delete = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM online WHERE last_activity < :gracePeriod OR id = :id');
  $delete->bindValue(':gracePeriod', $gracePeriod, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $delete->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $delete->execute();
  $insert = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO online(id, last_activity) VALUES (:id, :currentTime)');
  $insert->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $insert->bindValue(':currentTime', $currentTime, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $insert->execute();
  $count = $db->query('SELECT COUNT() AS visitors FROM online')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if ($count['visitors'] <= 1) {
    $visitors = 1;
  } else {
    $visitors = $count['visitors'];
  }
  echo $visitors;
  $db = null;
?>
```

[download the database to see the bug: online.sqlite](https://github.com/felladrin/online-visitors-counter/files/7907926/online.zip)

[image: SQlite where you can see null values inside table 1]

[image: SQlite where you can see null values inside table 2]

I edited the script like below, is there a good chance the following version will work fine?

```
<?php
  if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
  }
  $_SESSION['id'] = (isset($_SESSION['id'])) ? $_SESSION['id'] : uniqid();
  $secondsToConsiderOffline = 60;
  $hitonlinedb = "online.sqlite";
  try {
    if (!file_exists($hitonlinedb)) {
      $db = new PDO("sqlite:" . $hitonlinedb);
      $db->exec('CREATE TABLE online(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, last_activity INTEGER NOT NULL)');
    } else {
      $db = new PDO("sqlite:" . $hitonlinedb);
    }
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
  }
  $currentTime = time();
  $gracePeriod = $currentTime - $secondsToConsiderOffline;
  $id = $_SESSION['id'];
  $delete = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM online WHERE (last_activity < :gracePeriod OR last_activity IS NULL) OR (id = :id OR id IS NULL)');
  $delete->bindValue(':gracePeriod', ((is_null($gracePeriod) || empty($gracePeriod)) ? time() - 60 : $gracePeriod), PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $delete->bindValue(':id', ((is_null($id) || empty($id)) ? uniqid() : $id), PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $delete->execute();
  $insert = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO online(id, last_activity) VALUES (:id, :currentTime)');
  $insert->bindValue(':id', ((is_null($id) || empty($id)) ? uniqid() : $id), PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $insert->bindValue(':currentTime', ((is_null($currentTime) || empty($currentTime)) ? time() : $currentTime), PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $insert->execute();
  $count = $db->query('SELECT COUNT() AS visitors FROM online')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if ($count['visitors'] <= 1) {
    $visitors = 1;
  } else {
    $visitors = $count['visitors'];
  }
  echo $visitors;
  $db = null;
?>
```

Comment: You have defined `id` as NOT NULL. Why do you check if it is NULL?

Comment: Because in spite of everything null values ​​are written inside the database which I am trying to avoid in every way. See the attached screenshot.

Comment: Your db is corrupted. Since there is only 1 table with 2 rows it is better to delete it and recreate it.

Comment: I have deleted the database at least ten times and after a few days the problem returns.

Comment: Using `$count = $db->query('SELECT COUNT() AS visitors FROM online WHERE last_activity IS NOT NULL AND id IS NOT NULL')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` the counter counts the correct values but inside the database remain the null values.

Comment: Is a Race Condition that affects SQLite?

Comment: According to you, what is the possible cause? Server fault?

Comment: I hope fixed the issue. Thanks for your help.